# Thermodynamic equilibrium and state functions

Tags: thermodynamics

I would like to really understand the usage of thermodynamic state functions.

Here is what I understood.

I have a thermodynamic system, and I apply the first principle on it :

$$ dU=\delta W + \delta Q $$

I apply the second principle :

$$ \delta Q = T(dS-\delta S^c) $$ Where $\delta S^c$ is the term of entropy creation which is positive or 0.

I can thus rewrite the first principle like this :

$$ dU - \delta W - T dS = - T \delta S^c $$

So, I will have :

$$ dU - \delta W - T dS \leq 0 $$

Now with assumptions on the constraint on my system, I can find a function A such as $dA=dU - \delta W - T dS$.

For example if I have a system at constant volume and temperature (I assume there is not external work for simplification), I can write : $A=F=U-TS$, and I will have $dF=dU-TdS\leq 0$.

$F$ is thus in my example the free energy.

My question : Why do we say that $F$ is a state function ?
Indeed, I will have $dF=0$ only for a reversible transformation.

To summarize : can we say that F is a "nice" function for T,V=cte **irreversible** transformations because we know that when thoose transformations occurs we have "an equation" $dF=\delta W$ ?

Comment: F is a state function because U, T and S are state functions. $dF=0$ iff $dU-d(TS)=dU-TdS-SdT=0, this has nothing to do with the process being reversible *or* irreversible.

Comment: Ok, what I want to say is that we say that F is a thermodynamic potential. And a thermodynamic potential is minimum at equilibrium. So why do we say that F is the potential associated with $T,V=cte$ ? It is not minimum at equilibrium if the transformation is irreversible for example. AND even if it is a reversible transformation, $dF=0$ does'nt mean that we are at equilibrium (I never used this to get to this equation).

Comment: That F is minimum in equilibrium has nothing to do with the nature of the process that leads to the equilibrium, instead it is the consequence of you having assumed that the only interaction between the system and its surrounding is a constant temperature heat source (thermostat). Here minimum is to be understood in a local sense, that is for any infinitesimal virtual displacement compatible with the thermostat's temperature T we have both $\delta F = 0$ *and* $\delta^2 F>0$

Comment: Okay. Then i will reformulate my question according to your remark. How do you prove that F is minimum at equilibrium for a system at T,V fixed ? I think this is the thing I miss to understand well.

Comment: see http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks13/1305021p.pdf especially pages 77-80, Eq (113) and the footnote under it.